# Table that overflows it's container's paddings

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a `DIV` container with a `padding`, and a `table` inside it.

I need that table could *overflow padding* extending until DIV's borders.

Here the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ldetomi/7dnatyhn/). I thought about negative margins like in this rule:

```
div
{
    width:500px;
    padding:20px;
}

table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 -20px;
}
```

But this results only in left shifting of table and not also on a width augmentation.

Any suggest to obtain a table that *touch* both lateral DIV's borders?

Comment: Obviously no. Your solution is exactly like mine in which I set also negative right margin. I would like that also right borders touch each others. If instead of inner table I had an inner DIV I know that this solution works, but with table... no.

Comment: Why do you need to overflow the padding? Simply give padding-top and padding-bottom if you want the table to touch lateral div border. http://jsfiddle.net/augp7t7h/

Comment: The reason is simple. I posted a simplified example but I have other contents in this container, for example plain text, that need padding

Comment: Is there anything on the left and right of the table like you said plain text or something? Or it is there only on top and bottom of the table?

Comment: Top and bottom. It's an editorial content based on CKEditor include in LifeRay. Design wish that text has a lateral padding but not tables or images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `calc` function helps in this case:

```
table
{
    ...
    width: calc(100% + 40px);
}
```

This adds the initial width of the table and the used negative margins.

For an example see http://jsfiddle.net/7dnatyhn/3/

**EDIT**

If it helps: You could also add a margin to all elements except those which should get to the border of the container and remove the left and right padding of the container.

```
div {
    border: solid 1px red;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

div > * {
    margin: 0 20px;
}

div > table {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Could be a good solution but unfortunately, [compatible only since IE10](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

Comment: @LucaDetomi The issues with IE9 should not apply here. I guess if you want to support IE 8 (or Android Browser <= 4.3 and Opera Mini) the only way is a javascript workaround.